# Java error: CAP#1, int where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable: CAP#1 extends Object from capture of?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

With this generic tuple class

```
public class Pair< T1, T2 > {

  private final T1 first;
  private final T2 second;

  public Pair(T1 first, T2 second) {
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
  }

  public T1 getFirst() {
    return first;
  }

  public T2 getSecond() {
    return second;
  }

}
```

and this driver

```
public class PairDriver {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Pair<?, ?>[] s = new Pair<?, ?>[3];
    s[0] = new Pair<String, Integer>("a", 1);
    s[1] = new Pair<String, Integer>("b", 2);
    s[2] = new Pair<String, Integer>("c", 3);

    System.out.println( s[0].getFirst().getClass().getName() ); // Should be String
    System.out.println( s[0].getSecond().getClass().getName() ); // Should be Integer

    System.out.println( s[0].getFirst() );
    System.out.println( s[0].getFirst() + "!!!" ); // Operation works

    System.out.println( s[0].getSecond() );
    System.out.println( s[0].getSecond() + 2 ); // Operation FAILS...
  }

}
```

I get the following error:

```
pairDriver.java:17: error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'
    System.out.println( s[0].getSecond() + 2 ); // Operation FAILS...
                                         ^
  first type:  CAP#1
  second type: int
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

I'm confused as to why this happens. All the lines until the one marked `// Operation FAILS...` run -- the types seem correct and operations even work with the String , yet not the Integer.

As a follow-up: I've seen someone fix a similar error by replacing the wildcard `?` with a type. I don't understand why this worked in their case, but it's inapplicable here because declaring the array with types like `Pair<String, Integer>[] s = new Pair<String, Integer>[3];` results in a different error:

```
pairDriver.java:5: error: generic array creation
    Pair<String, Integer>[] s = new Pair<String, Integer>[3];
                                ^
1 error
error: compilation failed
```

I'm confused and curious as to why this happens as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm confused as to why this happens

As far as the compiler is concerned, you're adding some Object to an int.

It has no more information because the type of the second element in the pair is `?` (as in `Pair<?, ?>`). It doesn't know that the value is actually an Integer any more.

> As a follow-up

You can't create arrays with non-reifiable element types, because of type erasure.

A reifiable type is one where everything is known about the type at runtime. Non-generic types are reifiable; generic types where all type parameters are wildcards are reifiable; other generic types are not.

Generics and arrays are unhappy bedfellows. If you are using generics, use `List` instead.

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> s = new ArrayList<>();
s.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("a", 1));
s.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("b", 2));
s.add(new Pair<String, Integer>("c", 3));
```

Comment: For the follow-up, why isn't everything known at runtime about `Pair<String, Integer>[] s = new Pair<String, Integer>[3];`? We even know, at compile time, what the types are (String and Integer) because they're explicitly written. (I assume because "the types get erased per type erasure", so I guess I'm asking why type erasure happens.) And why are wildcard generics "reifiable" when other generics are not? And why do Lists work with non-reifiable types while arrays don't?

Comment: @user841495 type erasure happens because of a pragmatic decision when introducing generics to Java (in Java 5) not to break backwards compatibility. "We even know, at compile time" yes; but array assignments are checked at runtime, when the type information is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

The types of the data being added to your Pair class are erased at runtime.  All the compiler knows is that the data coming out of `getFirst()` and `getSecond()` are *something* that extends `Object`, but it doesn't know what that something is specifically.

Since `Object` has a `.toString()` method that is implicitly called when you use the string concatenation operator, `s[0].getFirst() + "!!!"` works just fine.  But `<? extends Object>` (which is all the the compiler knows about your type when you use it) isn't valid as the left-hand-side of the addition operator.

You can get around this by casting your result to an Integer like so:

```
System.out.println( (Integer) s[0].getSecond() + 2 );
```

But note that this is just you telling the compiler "trust me, this is definitely an Integer".